# rabbitmq-c consumer not receving all messages

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-c

I have ACK enabled on consumer and producer sending 2000 messages to server. What I see is only around 1700 messages are received at consumer. Can someone tell what is wrong?

I am running provided example code from rabbitmq-c library

## ./amqp_producer localhost 5672 1000

1000 ms: Sent 1000 - 1000 since last report (999 Hz)
PRODUCER - Message count: 2000
Total time, milliseconds: 2001
Overall messages-per-second: 999.083

root@ce-bras-mx240-e:/usr/sbin/rabbitmq_server-3.6.6 # sbin/rabbitmqctl list_connections send_cnt
Listing connections ...
2007
root@ce-bras-mx240-e:/usr/sbin/rabbitmq_server-3.6.6 # sbin/rabbitmqctl list_channels messages_unacknowledged
Listing channels ...
0
 # ./amqp_consumer localhost 5672
3275 ms: Received 1 - 1 since last report (0 Hz)
3275 ms: Received 2 - 1 since last report (1919 Hz)
3277 ms: Received 3 - 1 since last report (656 Hz)
4001 ms: Received 727 - 724 since last report (999 Hz)
5000 ms: Received 1727 - 1000 since last report (1001 Hz)

Only 1727 out of 2000 are received at consumer. The consumer is having no-ack flag set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

It was display issue only. There was bug in displaying the summary from amqp_consumer.cc in provided liberary which was incrementing the timestamp fo collecting next summary wrongly.